# pexpect behaves differently on same input

Tags: python, expect, pexpect

I use pexpect to login a juniper firewall and send the same command twice, I expect the output(I mean `s.before`) should be the same, but they are not. Why does pexpect behave differently on the same command?

Below is the python test file.

```
import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = '192.168.215.254'
    username = 'root'
    password = 'engine@1'
    s.login (hostname, username, password, original_prompt='root@developfirewall%', auto_prompt_reset=False)
    s.sendline ('cli')  # run a command
    s.PROMPT = 'root@developfirewall>'
    s.prompt()           # match the prompt
    print s.before       # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline ('configure')
    s.PROMPT = 'root@developfirewall#'
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    print 'start---------------------------------------------'
    s.sendline ('delete interfaces ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet address 10.123.0.13/32')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    print 'end---------------------------------------------'
    print 'start---------------------------------------------'
    s.sendline ('delete interfaces ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet address 10.123.0.13/32')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    print 'end---------------------------------------------'
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

Below is the stdout output, which I can see the same delete command returns different response.

```
 cli


 configure 
Entering configuration mode
Users currently editing the configuration:
  root terminal p1 (pid 64918) on since 2017-11-02 15:18:07 UTC, idle 01:34:05
      [edit]
  root terminal p0 (pid 64649) on since 2017-11-02 14:38:45 UTC, idle 02:07:38
      [edit]
  root terminal p4 (pid 64737) on since 2017-11-02 14:56:05 UTC, idle 01:55:21
      [edit]
The configuration has been changed but not committed

[edit]

start---------------------------------------------
 delete interfaces ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet addres
end---------------------------------------------
start---------------------------------------------
 ...0/5 unit 0 family inet address                       10.123.0.13/32 
delete interfaces ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet address 10.123.0.13/32warning: statement not found

[edit]

end---------------------------------------------
```

Below is the manual operation on juniper firewall, which response the same on the two delete commands.

```
[clouder@sky27 ~]$ ssh root@juniperfw
--- JUNOS 12.1X44-D35.5 built 2014-05-19 21:36:43 UTC

root@developfirewall% cli
root@developfirewall> configure 
Entering configuration mode
Users currently editing the configuration:
  root terminal p1 (pid 64918) on since 2017-11-02 15:18:07 UTC, idle 01:37:27
      [edit]
  root terminal p4 (pid 64737) on since 2017-11-02 14:56:05 UTC, idle 01:58:43
      [edit]
The configuration has been changed but not committed

[edit]
root@developfirewall# delete interfaces ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet address 10.123.0.13/32 
warning: statement not found

[edit]
root@developfirewall# delete interfaces ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet address 10.123.0.13/32    
warning: statement not found

[edit]
root@developfirewall#
```

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening is that there is a timeout whilst matching the prompt, and this causes the command to be sent too early. The default timeout for `s.prompt()` is set when you create the object with `pxssh.pxssh(timeout=...)`, and is 30 seconds. If the prompt call times out it will return False.

Instead, or as well as, debugging with `print s.before` you can setup a file to log to, or log to stderr: `pxssh.pxssh(logfile=sys.stderr)`.

Comment: in general, there are 2 main timing issues with "screen scraping" (an approached frowned upon nowadays): 1) the prompt takes to long to show up  2) the next command is sent too soon after (or worse, is sent before) the prompt shows up. meuh covered the first issue (pxssh.pxssh(timeout=...)), adding some sleep statement covers the first issue.